# Нужен сервис для определения внешнего ip своего компа, когда ты не дома

Tags: ip, синхронизация, dropbox, autohotkey

Посоветуйте способ того, как можно определить ip своей домашней машины для захода, например, с работы, через RDP.

Не хочу париться с динднс и ноу-айпи, на ум первым делом приходит только синхронизация в дропбоксе тесктового файла, с записью в него каким-нибудь скриптом текущего ip, думаю попробовать сделать на autohotkey.

Может ещё какие варианты кто предложит? Использую винду.

P.S. Если кто предложит какой-нибудь уже готовый скриптик на ahk - я не обижусь, но и не настаиваю. :)

Comment: Зря предполагаете, на роутере проброшен 3389 на локальный айпишник тачки, так что есть абсолютный что ни на есть прямой доступ к машине. А айпи и так понятно, что не статический, а динамический, было бы странно если бы я не могу зайти на 2ip.ru и посмотреть его там :)

Comment: В общем, наверное действительно не понятно из моего описания, что я хочу, поясняю. Мне просто нужно узнать белый динамический Ip-адрес моей сети, и тогда я на работе с ноутбука смогу заходить на свой домашний комп через удалённый рабочий стол, всё просто :) Сейчас думаю над таким вариантом - на домашнем компе всё равно установлен xampp, получить на пхп ip адрес да залить в файлик на дропбокс, только вот проблема как запускать пхп скрипт скажем через каждый час.

Comment: Всё-таки в первую очередь интересует: чем динднс и ноу-айпи не устраивают-то? Придуманы они специально для этого, роутеры их иногда непосредственно поддерживают.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы не знаете ip домашней машины то осмелюсь предположить что у вас не статический ip и в таком случае у вас не будет прямого доступа к ней из сети =), специально для Вашего случая придумали Teamviewer

Comment: Для динамического айпи прямой доступ зачастую тоже есть.

Answer (score 1):

Один из - [ipify.org](https://www.ipify.org/)
Из командной строки: `$ curl 'https://api.ipify.org'`
Далее отправляете себе на мыло.
Ну это вы и сами знаете..